# datalog input format of Z3

Tags: z3

I am looking for examples, specification, or documentation of the datalog input format that fixpoint Z3 accepts. I have looked for them in the source distribution, but did not find any. Are they available online or in any reports/papers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume your question is about the files with the ".datalog" suffix.
The online tutorial says: "Files with suffix .datalog are parsed using the BDDBDDB format. The format can be used for comparing benchmarks with the BDDBDDB tool."
I believe there should be a decent number of examples of files that the 
BDDBDDB tool accepts from the distribution page of that tool. Our parser may have some incompatibilities because I am unaware of a specification for this language.

You can also enter datalog problems in the SMT2 format. 
THe extensions to SMT2 are few and we describe them in http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/nbjorner/bmr-smt.pdf

Comment: bddbddb supports queries of the form "Gt("a", "d")?". I added this query to the end of the example datalog program given in fixedpoints Z3 doc under the section "Basic datalog", and ran both bddbddb and Z3. However, Z3 does not seem to support such syntax. Is there another syntax to query in the ".datalog" input format of Z3?

Answer (score 1):

The input format is described in the following online tutorials.

- http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/fixedpoints  (SMT 2.0 front-end)
- http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/tutorial/fixedpoints (Python front-end)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Btw, the above python doc page does not describe the input format of the input datalog file.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It shows how to directly access the datalog engine using Python.